# How to validate checkboxes using reactive form in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular2-forms

Tried to validate checkboxes using reactive form validation but not working.How to validate for all checkboxes should be selected.If anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need call your method to return ValidatorFn like this:

```
this.fg = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['Tiep Phan', [Validators.required]],
      bUnits: this.fb.array(
        this.businessUnits.map(() => this.fb.control('')),
        this.allcheckboxesSelect()
      )
    });
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-f3wbsn?file=app/app.component.ts

Btw, you can extract the method into a function to reduce complexity:

```
function allcheckboxesSelect(formArray: FormArray) {
 const totalSelected = formArray.controls
   .map(control => control.value)
   .reduce((prev, next) => next ? prev + next : prev, 0);
 return totalSelected >= formArray.length ? null : { required: true };
}

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 fg: FormGroup;
 businessUnits: any[] = [];

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   // do some stub to grab data
   this.businessUnits = [
     { name: 'BU 1', value: "1" },
     { name: 'BU 2', value: "2" },
     { name: 'BU 3', value: "3" }
   ];
   this.fg = this.fb.group({
     firstName: ['Tiep Phan', [Validators.required]],
     bUnits: this.fb.array(
       this.businessUnits.map(() => this.fb.control('')),
       allcheckboxesSelect
     )
   });

 }

 onSubmit() {
   console.log(this.fg);
 }

}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-qr4vtc?file=app/app.component.ts

Or using built-in validator function:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  fg: FormGroup;
  businessUnits: any[] = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // do some stub to grab data
    this.businessUnits = [
      { name: 'BU 1', value: "1" },
      { name: 'BU 2', value: "2" },
      { name: 'BU 3', value: "3" }
    ];
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['Tiep Phan', [Validators.required]],
      bUnits: this.fb.array(
        this.businessUnits.map(() => this.fb.control('', Validators.requiredTrue))
      )
    });

  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.fg);
  }

}
```

Demo with style for each control when it invalid:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-f1g1j8?file=app/app.component.css

Comment: Your concept not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6d7u86?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: unchecked checkboxes label text should be red..checked checkboxes label text should be block..

Comment: I have used this in app.component.css:.ng-invalid{
  color:red; 
}
but not working  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-qr4vtc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Krithik you need include style first https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-qr4vtc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: another solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-f1g1j8?file=app/app.component.css

Comment: @tiep phan: can you use default class ng-invalid and ng-valid? Using this can u change parent label text color?

Comment: @Apple Orange: I have an example with ng-invalid, but if you use this css class, it will affect whole form, because if one control invalid, the form is invalid too. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-qr4vtc?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @TiepPhan: Not working...I have edited my question. I want to apply css for main.ng-invalid of div.please resolve this issue:   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-d9zuvd?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: you really need to improve basic understand html css first. `main` is a class, you must provide correct selector https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-34n2kb?file=app/app.component.css

Comment: .main.ng-invalid is my global css so i can not edit.It will not work for input class. So i need to use parent of input like <div class="main ng-invalid ......><input type="text"></div>